# Custom Data Viewer in SSIS

Tags: ssis, components

Can custom data viewers be written in SSIS? I have a good deal of experience in writing transformation components, and have a need for a very specific viewer.

Does SSIS have provisions for this? I haven't been able to find any reference to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend SSIS functionality by writing custom "things". If you cannot write a custom "viewer" you can attach to a flow, you might be able to write a custom transformation (async) or custom destination that could do what you need to do

Reference material here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345161.aspx